# "Not an answer" flag declined. Was failure to answer not obvious?

Tags: support, declined-flags

I raised the "Not An Answer" flag on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58681518/924299).

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26431066/924299) asks what the combination of PHP's `continue` and `break` means in a specific context:

> I am new to PHP and saw the code below online. It has continue 2 and break together in switch/case statement. What does it mean?

The attempted answer doesn't address that question, but instead references a non-existent error and offers a solution to a problem isn't demonstrated in the question.

> goto the corresponding lines as mentioned in the error and change continue; into continue 2;

Yet my flag was declined:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

I suspect that it was declined because the reason for flagging was not obvious, as mentioned in [How do I properly use the “Not an Answer” flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185074/234388):

> ...moderators can't see the question or comments in context without clicking further, which they probably won't do unless there's an obvious reason to look for additional context.

Should I have used the "in need of moderator intervention" flag instead to provide more detail?

Comment: Even if the post *"references a non-existent error and **offers a solution** to a problem isn't demonstrated in the question."* it's still an **attempt at an answer** ....no matter how useless. So it is an answer just a bad one. DV & move on.

Comment: Yes, an attempt to answer a question that wasn't asked. Does that count?

Comment: I imagine the downvotes are because the answer to your question is in the answers to the META discussion to which you link: "wrong answers. Downvote them and use comments to explain what is wrong. The NAA flag is for answers that are not even wrong, i.e., they do not even live on the right–wrong axis (for the respective question)."

Comment: I don't consider a random or irrelevant answers to be on the right-wrong axis. It's like asking why the sky is blue and answering "just add seven and three".

Comment: That makes it a very wrong answer, not "not an answer".

Comment: I challenge that definition. Answers "attempt to answer *the* question", not just *any* question. Moving on. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: voted to delete. I'm not sure what the post is supposed to be an answer to, but it's certainly not that question. Maybe wires got confused?

Comment: @showdev if you want to "challenge that definition" you should post explicit "feature-request". Make sure to review diamond mods' answers to same "NAA/VLQ declined" before posting the request.